# Angular2 EventEmitter and preventDefault()

Tags: angular, preventdefault, eventemitter

Is there a way in Angular2 to somehow prevent the default for events using the EventEmitter?

I have the following scenario:

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<button (click)="clickemitter.emit($event); onClick($event)" [style.color]="color"><ng-content></ng-content></button>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Output clickemitter: EventEmitter<MouseEvent> = new EventEmitter();

  private color: string = "black";

  constructor() {

  }

  private onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if(!event.defaultPrevented) //gets called before the observers of clickemitter
      this.color = "red";
    else this.color = "blue";
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <my-component (clickemitter)="$event.preventDefault()">Hello Angular</my-component>
  `,
  directives: [MyComponent]
})
export class App {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

I made a Plunker for this, too: https://plnkr.co/edit/yIoF1YgvkiZLBPZ6VHTs?p=preview

**The Problem**
If i click on the button the color of the button wouldn't turn blue as it should but it turns red instead.
This might be because EventEmitter.emit()/next() seem to work asynchronous. 
I tried to solve this problem by also subscribing my onClick() method at the emitter and just call *clickemitter.emit($event)* in my button (click) event handler. This would work for the Plunker Demo when i did it in ngAfterInit(). But what if someone subscribes to the clickemitter later? My component would get called before that observer again and my component would be inconsistent.

**The Question**
How can i ensure that my component onClick() handler will get called at the very last to guarantee that no other observer can prevent the default behavior afterwards? Or is there a complete different way of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 19):

To solve this problem use this in your html template

```
<button (click)="clickemitter(a,b,c); $event.stopPropagation();" 
        [style.color]="color" >
        <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

As `$event.stopPropagation();` works to stop default click event and your button only call event that written in `(click)="...."`  which is `clickemitter.emit(a,b,c)`

Maybe this is help full to you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, this helped with a form in a dummy component triggering a submission in the parent component where I'd called the event 'submit'.

Comment: this saved me because I have an ng-bootstrap popover, and inside that template I have a <button (click)> that was removing domNodes (ngIf). if I didn't have the $event.stopPropagation() the popover would close upon click.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `return false;`
here is code which i have used for **prevent default**

```
  @HostListener('click') open(){
      this._isOpen = !this._isOpen;
      return false;
  }
```

And for **stopPropagation**

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
 onClick(e) {
  alert("we have performed click");
  e.stopPropagation();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented event.preventDefault like this

```
export class ObserveComponent{
   onSubmit(event:Event){
     event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

stopped page reload every time I tried to access value of a key which is not exist in the object